# Update Dataverse using SQL stataments

Tags: power-automate, dataverse

I have a table which has 15 columns in Dataverse. 9 columns from the table are updated/filled up using excel file from sharepoint using power automate flow.
The remaining 6 columns has to be calculated based on the previously inserted 9 columns.
To update the remaining 6 columns we have SQL update statements ready to use. But I dont find a way to fill it up using update commands. I can only find update a row command in power automate. Please suggest me a way to update the remaining 6 columns

Answer (score 0):

Dataverse does not natively support SQL UPDATE statements. To use this approach you'd need to use the [SQL 4 CDS tool in XrmToolBox](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/MarkMpn.SQL4CDS/) to run the query after Power Automate has imported the initial data.

To do it all within Power Automate you'll need to re-work your SQL statement into the equivalent Power Automate expressions to calculate the additional column values.